# NSBitmapRep, CGContextRef and how to handle large images

Tags: macos

I have a Knife tool as part of WildTools in PowerCADD that cuts objects in the drawing.  I did this the 'wrong' way some years ago by using NSBitmapImageRep to compare and set pixels.  It works but it's horribly slow, I'm embarrassed and I'm working on fixing the problem.

The approach that I'm using now is to use an NSBitmapImageRep to draw a mask offscreen, then use a CGContextRef, clipping the CGContextRef with the mask, then use CGContextDrawImage with the original CGImageRef to get the masked image.

There's no problem getting this to work, but for a single knife cut of an image, I have to do this twice, once for each side of the knife cut.

The problem I'm running into is with very large bitmaps with say 14000 x 9000 pixels in a 300-400 dpi image.  In this case when I call CGBitmapContextCreate I'll get a NULL context and the whole things falls apart.

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to do this with a single NSBitmapImageRep for the four operations.  My thought is to create an NSImage, lock focus on it so the drawing goes into it to create a mask.  Then use NSImage drawInRect with an NSCompositeClear operation to mask out the unwanted part of the image.  If I never get any bits into the single NSBitmapImageRep then perhaps I can do it all with a single NSBitmapImageRep.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Seems like you really want a fresh approach. You might want to look at Core Image and the Accelerate framework.

Comment: AppKit drawing is great and simple, but Core Image is OpenGL backed.

Comment: Thanks. I began with CoreImage but it crashed in just making a CoreImage context.